# Are there novels in the Marvel comic universe?

Tags: marvel, comics, dc, marvel-cinematic-universe

Growing up I liked the idea of comic books and graphic novels, but I never could read them. I think it was just a matter of patience - they didn't seem to move fast enough for me. Plus I would read a comic book and not enough happened that I felt like it was worth while. I always enjoyed hearing about the Marvel universe from my friends who consumed comic books on a regular basis, but it was never something I enjoyed. I've read, and continue to read regular novels though.

Now with all the great Marvel universe movies I find myself once again wanting to read more about it. So I am wondering if there is a non-graphical novel set in the Marvel universe? Or maybe there are graphic novels that move along at a better pace. I've recently started reading Manga with my boys, and I find I can read those. So either I've changed, or Manga is written different enough from domestic comics.

So are there other written forms of consuming the Marvel universe besides the traditional comic / graphic novel? I like DC and other comic universes too, so if there is a good one in DC then I might be interested in that.

Comment: You may also be interested in George R. R. Martin's [*Wildcards*](http://www.amazon.com/Wild-Cards-I-Trust/dp/0765365073) series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are. There is a general list to get you started [here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_novels_based_on_comics). Marvel, DC, and other publishers all have prose versions of some of their comics.

Some of the ones listed are novelizations of movies, others are adaptations of comic book stories. There are also others which are completely new stories written for the new medium.

Marvel, specifically, has created a separate [Mangaverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Mangaverse), and at one point, teamed up with Del Ray Books to publish a Shoujo Manga called [X-Men: Misfits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Misfits).

Comment: Should have known there was a Wikipedia article about it.

Answer (score 2):

The 4 issue Wolverine Saga is far closer to a traditional novel than a graphic novel; although it is largely a re-telling of previously published comics. If you're just getting started in the Marvel 616 universe however it is a nice way to transition over.